# Limiting # of characters per line

Tags: java

I'm a beginner and I'm having trouble trying to display the output so that if its too big it will move it to the next line.

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class numberBracket {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("howMany: ");
        int howMany = scanner.nextInt();
    
        
        System.out.println("lineLength: ");
        int lineLength = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();
        
        printNumbers(howMany, lineLength);
         
    }
        
    public static void printNumbers(int howMany, int lineLength) {
        Integer charLength =  Integer.valueOf(lineLength); 
        
        for(int i = 1; i <= howMany; i ++) {
            
            String t = "[" + i + "]";
            
            
            while(t.length() > charLength ) {
                int index = t.lastIndexOf(' ', charLength);
                System.out.print(t.substring(0, index));
                t = t.substring(index + 1);
            }
            System.out.print(t);
        }
}
}
```

So if they enter 10 for the lineLength it would be

```
[1][2][3]

[4]
```

and if they entered 12 it would be

```
[1][2][3][4]
```

Comment: You have to sum up the length of your current line and check against that (plus the length of the "next" string). Forget about all of your `lastIndexOf` and `substring` calls. Also you don't have a single `println` to create that new line.

Comment: You don't need this statement
`Integer charLength =  Integer.valueOf(lineLength); `

You  can search about "Autoboxing and unboxing in Java" to learn more.

Comment: @Huka: you don't need the whole `lastIndexOf` and therefore you also don't need it's parameters. And if you needed it, `lastIndexOf` takes an `int` anyways, and neither manual conversion nor autoboxing to `Integer` is necessary.

Comment: @cyberbrain
I'm sorry but I don't know why did you mention me.

Comment: @Huka I mentioned you because it was a reaction to your comment. Obviously the OP is using autounboxing already, as `String.lastIndexOf` takes `int` as second parameter while the code provides an `Integer` there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this snippet:

```java
    public static void printNumbers(int howMany, int lineLength) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int length = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= howMany; i++) {
            String t = "[" + i + "]";

            if (length + t.length() > lineLength) {
                sb.append("\n");
                length = 0;
            }
            
            length += t.length();

            sb.append(t);
        }
        
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
```

Comment: You should make your input check of the `lineLength` parameter a bit more sophisticated: first I would throw an `IllegalArgumentException` here instead of returning silently. Next the minimum length of 3 is not sufficient, because if `howMany` is > 9 you will need more space than 3 characters per line.
And finally (and this is the biggest bug here): after the first reach of the line length limit, you print a newline after each number, because you don't reset the comparison of line length value to 0 for a new line.

Comment: @cyberbrain
I updated my answer to fix the bug.
Thank you for pointing it.

Comment: A more sophisticated parameter check could be `linelength < Math.floor(Math.log10(howMany)) + 3` (the `log10` calculates the number of digits - 1 for the biggest number to print, so I add 3 to get the real number of digits plus the brackets)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void printNumbers(int howMany, int lineLength) {
    String printed = "";

    for (int i = 1; i <= howMany; i++) {
        String t = "[" + i + "]";
        if ((printed.length() + t.length()) > lineLength) {
            printed = "";
            System.out.println();
        }
        printed += t;
        System.out.print(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Really, string concatenation in a loop?? Ouch! Use a `StringBuilder`!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to check if it has room in the current line before printing.

If it does have room print it, if it doesn't, print in a new line.

```
public static void printNumbers(int howMany, int lineLength) {
    int alreadyPrintedLength = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= howMany; i ++) {
      String t = "[" + i + "]";
      int actualCharLength = t.length();
      boolean hasRoomInCurrentLine = (alreadyPrintedLength + actualCharLength) <= lineLength;
      if (hasRoomInCurrentLine) {
        System.out.print(t);
        alreadyPrintedLength += actualCharLength;
      } else {
        System.out.print(System.lineSeparator() + t);
        alreadyPrintedLength = actualCharLength;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `t.length()` instead of the "complicated" calculation of `actualCharLength` (even it's name is misleading, it's not the length of char)?

Comment: @cyberbrain you are right, edited my answer. I will leave the `actualCharLength` var for better readability.

Comment: Next bug: you are adding the "actualCharLength" twice to `alreadyPrintedLength` for the comparison, once in the `+=` operator and second in the comparison. 
And (to my opinion) to read a variable name that is longer than a quite obvious function call does _not_ improve readabilty. 
Better rename `t` to something better understandable.

Comment: @cyberbrain thanks, didn't see that. Edited.